# Trying to hide element on mobile devices

Tags: css, wordpress, hide, element

On my Wordpress site I have a Bitcoin tip widget that I would like to hide on handheld mobile devices.

This is the current CSS from the plugin:

```
.bitcointips-widget {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #191919;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 16px 0;
  padding: 16px;
}

.bitcointips-widget * {
  clear: none;
}

.bitcointips-widget:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.bitcointips-widget .qrcode {
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  width: 125px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bitcointips-widget .contents {
  clear: none;
  margin-left: 136px;
}

.bitcointips-widget .contents h2 {
  margin: -2px 0 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.bitcointips-widget .contents p {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.bitcointips-widget .pluginhome {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 4px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bitcointips-widget .pluginhome a, .bitcointips-widget .pluginhome a:visited {
  color: silver;
}


.bitcointips-widget .pluginhome a:hover {
  color: inherit;
}
```

This is what it looks like in the page's source:

```
<div class="bitcointips-widget"><div class="qrcode"><a href="bitcoin:19yvKvsuc5jv46NS6Hk8se4B9Lz7QVqSoD"><img src="http://altcoinpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/newbitcoinaddress_125.png" width="125" height="125" /></a></div><div class="contents"><h2>Like this post? Tip me with Bitcoin!</h2><p><a href="bitcoin:19yvKvsuc5jv46NS6Hk8se4B9Lz7QVqSoD">19yvKvsuc5jv46NS6Hk8se4B9Lz7QVqSoD</a></p><p>If you enjoyed reading this article, please consider tipping me using Bitcoin. All donations go towards supporting this website and its writers. Your generosity is very much appreciated.</p></div><div class="pluginhome"><a href="https://bitcoin.org/">Get a Bitcoin Wallet</a></div></div>
```

If anyone can help me with this problem, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Greg.

Comment: This is the website where the bitcoin tip widget can be viewed: http://altcoinpress.com

Comment: I've tried several variations of the answer by sticksu

Comment: There is no element with the bitcointips-widget class in your website...

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS media queries:

```
@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
  .bitcointips-widget {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Should I just add this entry to the top of the CSS code?

Comment: To the bottom of your CSS, and it should work. Basically if it detects that the viewport is smaller than 640px if will apply the display: none property on that class

Comment: I first tried adding it to the top, and then the bottom of the file, but the widget is still being displayed on my Samsung Galaxy S2.

Comment: try display: none !important;

Comment: Are you sure the element is not inside on an iframe or something?

Comment: with current display sizes being basically desktop size in terms of pixels, how would we go about doing it now?